# Why the ASM of arm64 intrinsics vdupq_laneq_s64 is DUP Vd.2D,Vn.D[lane] but DUP Vd.2D,Vn.2D[lane]?

Tags: arm64

[The offical documents of Arm64 intrinsics of vdupq_laneq_s64.](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#q=vdupq_laneq_s64)
And its ASM instruction is "DUP Vd.2D,Vn.D[lane]".

In my personal opinion, the ".2D" means that the 16 bytes vector will be handle by 8Bytes as a whole. So the Vn.D should be writen into Vn.2D.

Am I wrong?
How should I figure out that instruction?

---

Why the ASM instruction for vdupq_laneq_s64 is
DUP Vd.2D,Vn.D[lane]
instead of
DUP Vd.2D,Vn.2D[lane]?

Comment: But I don't think I understand your question.  The title "Why X is Y but Z" is not grammatical.  Are you asking about the assembly syntax, or about what the instruction actually does?

Comment: The idea is that `DUP V0.2D, V1.D[1]` should take the upper 64-bit element from V1, and copy it into both 64-bit elements of V0.

Comment: So... this is a question asking people to validate or invalidate your opinions? Maybe see [help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [help/dont-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @starball: I think "opinion" is just the phrasing; OP is explaining their *understanding* of some technical issue and is asking if it is correct.  This is perfectly on topic.  The problem is that I can't exactly tell what issue they refer to, or what it is they understand about it.

Comment: @NateEldredge forgive my poooor English. Orz.   I have updated the question now.